# Why am I getting a SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement error?

Tags: python

I got this error message, how to solve it ? And if anyone can explain what this piece of code means?

```
>>> x = 1
if x == 1:
    # indented four spaces
    print ("x is 1.")
```

`SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement`

Comment: So where are you putting this code? How did you enter it, typing it by hand or copy-pasting? Your attempt at marking up the code really makes it unclear exactly what you see and what you copied.

Comment: I put this piece of code in my Python 3.4.3 shell, copy-pasted it. Its from the Indentation section of this tutorial : http://www.learnpython.org/en/Hello%2C_World%21 --- I copy pasted it into my Python Shell and it gave the error. And why did I get negative reputation points for asking a legitimite question weird ?

Comment: Is this posted into IDLE or your console? What happens when you paste *just* the `x = 1` line, for example?

Comment: In your example, the first line begins with `>>>` but the second line does not; this indicates that the Python interpreter does not recognize the second line as a separate statement.  Somehow your cut-and-paste is joining the two lines together.  Try just typing it by hand and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Note that the interactive interpreter is different from pasting this into a file; the interactive interpreter can only handle one top-level statement at a time (so you'd have to make sure that the *previous* statement was completed, by hitting ENTER again if there is still a `...` prompt).

Comment: >>> x = 1
>>> if x == 1:
 print("x is 1.")
 
x is 1.                               This is the result I got when i typed it in by hand.

Comment: @CaiGengyang: so it is working now? What was different in how you pasted the code?

Comment: Yea it works now ... the difference was that I typed by hand instead of copy and pasting and when both statements (x = 1) and if (x == 1) begins with >>> , the code works

Comment: @CaiGengyang When in doubt, check your copy/pasted text in a hex editor. You should see four hex bytes with a value of 20 in a row if you have a four-space indentation. If not, convert indents to space in your hex/text editor.